# Android TV - app that runs 24/7 in foreground mode

Tags: java, android, android-tv

I'm trying to create a kind of interactive dashboard app for Android TV.
The app mainly targets Android 11 and Android 9 (but not critical).
The idea is to have an app that runs 24/7 on Xiaomi Android TV device as long as it stays foreground.
The problem I faced so far is that operating system at Xiaomi Android TV after some period of time unpredictably kills my app, returns to the home screen and launches screensaver. After numerous experiments I could prolong my app's life from 5-6 hours to 2-3 days, but the problem persists.
And what's important here is that when the app goes to background - it's fine, Android can do whatever it needs to do with it, however when it's in foreground mode - DON'T TOUCH IT.
And one more thing, I don't need to publish my app to Play Market - I just install APK from USB stick, so that I can ask for any permission I need to run my app.

First thing I did was:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

The app worked 5-6 hours before getting terminated by the OS.
Then I tried to dig further and added wake lock and enabled sustained performance mode:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
...
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK,
        "MyApp::MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
...
getWindow().setSustainedPerformanceMode(true);
```

The code above prolonged my app's life up to 2-3 days, which is better than it was before but still not a 24/7 I need. Just like I said, Xiaomi TV with Android 11 still terminates my app, goes to home screen, and then displays screen saver after 5 minutes of idle.
What else did I try.. ah "Ignore Battery Optimization" feature. I know that it's primarily for background services to keep them alive but decided to give it a try:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
...
Intent intent = new Intent();
String packageName = getPackageName();
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
if (pm != null && !pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

but the screen for disabling battery optimization for my app does not appear on both Android TV 11 emulator and real Xiaomi TV device. In fact, nothing happens when I call `startActivity`. Nevertheless I wen to system settings and disabled battery optimization for my app manually. And guess what - that didn't help either.
Tried to write sticky background service to restart my app by launching it's main activity every 10 seconds, but when I terminate my app, service's `startActivity` does nothing as well.
I'm kinda stuck and wondering if that's really possible on Android?

Comment: It sounds like you need to control the hardware, installing an Android build that behaves in the way that you want.

Comment: So you're saying it's impossible with device out of the box?

Comment: I am saying that you are at the mercy of the device manufacturer.